# open a terminal session from php

Tags: php, unix

i'm trying to write a php page that
call for a server program like

```
gdb
```

the problem is if i did

```
<?php
exec(" gdb code", $out); 
?>
```

the PHP call for the  command and exist
 BUT what i want to do is like open a "terminal" session
where the user enter commands in that program like

```
    gdb code
    ..
    break main
    ..
    run
```

and after each command i give him the output and he give me the next command 
and it won't work if i did it  like this

```
     <?php
    exec(" gdb code", $out);
 exec(" break", $out);
 exec(" run", $out);
    ?>
```

and the PHP can be run from a browser 
and i tried it with pro_open

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("file", "/var/www/err.log", "a")
);

$cwd = '/var/www';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');
$StdErr='';
$process = proc_open('/bin/bash', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], "gcc code   ");
    fwrite($pipes[0], " break main");
    fflush($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    while(!feof($pipes[1]))    {
          echo fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
           }
    echo $StdErr;
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    echo "command returned : $return_value\n";
}
```

and thank you .

Comment: There seem to be a lot of questions like this, where I have to explain him/her what AJAX is and why it would be bad idea, to use PHP interactively (like in the often seen `while(true){echo "$x % done..."; sleep(1);}` loop). Is there a generic answer to this kind of questions?

Comment: Well he didn't say he was running it in a webbrowser; perhaps just in the console?

Comment: i know AJAX  but the problem is i every function in PHP execute the command in one piece and exit i wan't to be able to run those "mini command" inside the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** just saw you do try it from a browser. There is absolutely no simple way to do this. If you want an interactive session from the browser, you must run a separate daemon process and forward commands to it from PHP (and return output).

This is not simple at all; so if you still feel like doing this.. I would recommend starting with how to create a deamon; and then write a tcp socket server (or other IPC).

Excuse the crappy grammar

Comment: i did tried this method but i couldn't solve the problem please can you explain more

Comment: You gotta show some code snippets. And you do do this from a console right? Now through a webserver & browser?

Comment: But yea, update your question with what you tried with proc_open and how it failed.